# Codeigniter: When i do search the pagination page still remains

Tags: codeigniter, search, pagination

I have a problem when i do search the pagination number still remains in the url result to showing no resuts. for example when i click a pagination link my url looks like this example/index.php/example/info/10 then when i do search, the url now the url looks like this example/index.php/example/info/10?search=word

How can i fixed this problem

#### Controller

```
public function info($offset=0)
{       
    $this->load->library('pagination');

    $search = $this->input->get('search');
        $page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;


    if($this->input->get('search')){

        $count = $this->ticketing_mdl->count_all_ticket();
        $config['total_rows'] = $count;
        $config['suffix'] = '?' . http_build_query($_GET, '', "&");
        $config['base_url'] = "/ticketing/index.php/ticketing/info";
        $config['first_url'] = "/ticketing/index.php/ticketing/info?search=$search";

    }else{
    $this->db->where('is_valid','1');
    $config['total_rows'] = $this->db->count_all_results('db_ticketing.tr_ticket');
    $config['base_url'] = "/ticketing/index.php/ticketing/info";
    }
    $limit = 10;
    $config['per_page'] = $limit;
    $config['num_links'] = $limit;

    $config['full_tag_open'] = '<div><ul class="pagination pagination-centered">';
    $config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul></div>';
    $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['cur_tag_open'] = "<li class='disabled'><li class='active'><a href='#'>";
    $config['cur_tag_close'] = "<span class='sr-only'></span></a></li>";
    $config['next_tag_open'] = "<li>";
    $config['next_tagl_close'] = "</li>";
    $config['prev_tag_open'] = "<li>";
    $config['prev_tagl_close'] = "</li>";
    $config['first_tag_open'] = "<li>";
    $config['first_tagl_close'] = "</li>";
    $config['last_tag_open'] = "<li>";
    $config['last_tagl_close'] = "</li>";

    $config['first_link'] = 'First';        

    $this->pagination->initialize($config);

    $data['pagination'] = $this->pagination->create_links();

    $data['ticket_list'] = $this->ticketing_mdl->get_all_ticket($limit,$page, $offset);

    $this->load->view('ticketing/header');
    $this->load->view('ticketing/left_menu');
    $this->load->view('ticketing/info',$data);
}
```

Comment: Change your url $config['first_url'] = "/ticketing/index.php/ticketing/info?search=$search"; to whatever url you want.

Answer (score 0):

Let me know if i am right.

I think you can control it by defining routes.

Set your **$config['base_url']** of pagination library like `example/index.php/search` 
and define routes (application/config/routes.php) like

```
$route['search'] = "example/info";
$route['search/(:num)'] = "example/info/$1";
```

comment this **$config['first_url'] = "/ticketing/index.php/ticketing/info?search=$search";** 
And dont forget to set the html form action="echo site_url('search');" method="get"

I hope this will give you some help.